# How to get App Page ID from Application Object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application and created an app page in the app settings. But it seems they don't really have a connection to each other unless I want to set up my app as a tab although the page appears in the app's advanced settings.

Is there a way to get the App Page's ID from the Application Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current official documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) I would say that you can not get that information from the Application object.

What I don't really get is why you need to get that?  Don't you already know the app page id/url?

Comment: I don't want to add the App Page ID to my database if it's possible to get it from the Application Object via the Graph API.

Comment: You don't have to put it in a database, you can also put it in a configuration file that you load at runtime, or even hardcoded...
any of those options seem, to me at least, better for this specific task.  why?  cuz you only have one app (right?) and why waste a http request for a api call (it takes time you know) if you already have that info?

Comment: So App and App Page do not have any usable relation to each other and there is just the button "Go to App" which makes out the difference between App Page and a normal Page?

Comment: basically, yeah, that's how it is...  Just until recently, each application had an application page, which was different than a regular fb page (and it had almost the same address as the app: http://www.facebook.com/APP_NAME instead of http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME), but facebook changed it in the last months so that the app page is just a regular page, but you can set which page it is in the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get that from the 'link' field?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: no, that takes you to the canvas page..  for example, try the example in the page you gave the link for (the graffiti application), and click the "link".

Comment: The link field provides the App Link. I need the link to the App Page instead.